# static class variables

Tags: python, static, class-variables

I can't understand how works the code below:

```
class Host:
    name = None
    fileList = []
    def __init__(self, hostName):
        self.name = hostName    
    def AddInfo(self,file):
        self.fileList.append(file)          
    def Cleanup(self):
        self.fileList   = []
```

I create 2 instances:

```
h1 = Host("hostName1")
h1.AddInfo("h1")
h1.Cleanup()
print h1.fileList, Host.fileList

h2 = Host("hostName2")
h2.AddInfo("h2")
print h2.fileList, Host.fileList
```

the result is:

```
h1.fileList = [], Host.fileList = ['h1']
h2.fileList = ['h1', 'h2'], Host.fileList = ['h1', 'h2']
```

why `Host.fileList` value is changed - I assigned new values to the instance only? why `h2.fileList` has such value - I was expecting `['h2']` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably easist to see by stepping through your code:

```
h1 = Host("hostName1")  #After __init__:h1.filelist -> Host.filelist
h1.AddInfo("h1")        #After AddInfo: h1.filelist -> Host.filelist
h1.Cleanup()            #After Cleanup: h1.filelist is a new list

h2 = Host("hostName2")  #After __init__:h2.filelist -> Host.filelist (which already has 'h1' inserted)
h2.AddInfo("h2")        #After AddInfo: h2.filelist -> Host.filelist
```

Inside your methods, when using `self.filelist`, python looks to see if the instance has a `filelist` attribute first.  If the instance doesn't have that attribute, python looks for the attribute on the class the instance belongs to.  when you do `self.filelist=[]` in `Cleanup`, you are giving the instance the attribute `filelist`.

Comment: Do you mean the instance variable was created just after "=" in `Cleanup` not in `self.fileList.append`?

Comment: @Francheska -- Of course self.fileList.append doesn't create a new instance variable.  I'm not sure I understand your comment.  I've added `After` to the comments in the code above.  Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 3):

This is basic Python (as in "Python is not Java").

Attributes declared at the class level are class attributes, not instance attributes. To declare an instance attribute, assign directly to `self` inside a method, as you do with `self.name` in `__init__`.

Comment: I know this example is ambiguous - I will never use such code in real. I'm just trying to understand why class level variable Host.fileList has such value in my example?

Comment: It's not ambiguous at all, and your code is fine if you want a class variable. It has that value because that's how the semantics of Python are defined: accessing a class variable via `self` is allowed, but it's still a class variable.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in class scope are defined by class. You should create your variables in `__init__`.

```
def __init(self, hostName):
    self.name = hostName
    self.fileList = []
```